# Has anybody achieved Virtual Keyboard in angular applications?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Please let me know if there any plugins or references to integrate virtual keyboard in angular applications.

Comment: this gives me the following error : Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/rxjs' in 'E:\Projects\QC\node_modules\@protacon\ng-virtual-keyboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5

Comment: without your code it will be hard to help

Comment: Shall i tell another simple vitual keyboard for you.

Comment: Sure any virtual keyboard just let me know i will implement it

Comment: please see iam updated screenshot for working example.you have to download that all files and put assets folder and set actual path as index.html file

Comment: yes js & css now fixed now only error i am getting is of keyboard icon where to put that ?

Comment: In keyboard.js file go line 76 update like this   this.VKI_imageURI = "assets/keyboard.png";

Comment: Thanks brother you saved my day. All works like charm..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple virtual keyboard for you. You can customize color image all things is possible.
Html file,

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Keyboard</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="keyboard.css">
      <script src="keyboard.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Virtual Keyboard</p>
        <input type="text" value="" class="keyboardInput">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is an link for download js file and css, .png image file,

```
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard.js
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard.css
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard.png
```

i hope it's simple and easy to use. Just try this once.

output,
[image]

Edit:-
[image]

index.html file,

[image]

you have to update one line for set path keyboard png file,

keyboard.js file,

Line no 76 change like this,

[image]

Thats all it works well.

Comment: Wil it work in angular applications ?

Comment: yes sure it works angular application i tried before.

Comment: ok let me try all these files i will give link in main index.html file correct ? http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard.js
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard.css
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard.png

Comment: its not working in angular 6 application

Comment: no first two files css and js you have to add index.html file download and put some assets folder your app. And also put keyboard.png in same assets folder

Comment: iam updated screenshot see now works angular application

Comment: hello Karnana Can we disable the above  keyborad selection currently it is selected to US international

Comment: Wait i will try and let me know

Comment: this returns null value when used with reactive forms

Comment: When is submit it it returns blank value in console

Comment: Doesn't load anything. Don't see the keyboard image too.